# Permission error while accessing uploaded files

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, pdf

I have created custom field section in contribution page and I have one file upload field. Uploaded file is not able to access in View contribution (logged in as super admin), getting below error.

[image]

The only way to access this file is using edit contribution, the file is getting downloaded if I click the link.

Comment: which version of CiviCRM are you using? - I tried with 4.7.23 and worked as excepted but for some reason the file extension got saved as unknown

Comment: The latest one 4.7.29

Comment: please try to reproduce the error against - http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: in this URL (dmaster.demo.civicrm.org) the uploaded file is not displaying. I have created a new custom field under contribution and uploaded one PDF file, while viewing this contribution its not displaying attached file.

Comment: please check (dmaster.demo) I have uploaded a PDF file and i can see the same in view contribution - are you trying to view somewhere else ?

Comment: This is an issue with URL. /administrator/ is not there before index.php? in view only mode. Current URL (/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/file&reset=1&id=13&eid=81).
Recommanded URL(/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/file&reset=1&id=13&eid=81) 
so which file I need to edit to add this /administrator/ in file URL?

Comment: It sounds like you are using Joomla.  In which case you would be better testing in http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/.  The dmaster site is for Drupal.